# Thymeleaf iterate through a nested list to create table <th> title and the <td> text for golf app

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Hi Im relatively new with Spring and Thymeleaf but I am creating a disc golf CRUD app and I'm able to add a course with a Course object which has a oneToMany relation to ParList. All works fine I can add a course but a course doesnt always have 18 holes. How can I show this dynamically so a 9 hole courses table has 9 columns, a 14 - 14 columns etc?
I have tried using th:each="par, iterStat : ${course.parLists}" and trying to use iterStat.index but I can't quite get it.
So how can I get the index of the list and use it in the hole number  and display the courses par  without repeating like I have below?
So my data looks like this:

```
Course{id=3, name='Legende Main', parLists=[ParList{parListId=10, parHole1='3', parHole2='3', parHole3='3', parHole4='3', parHole5='3', parHole6='3', parHole7='3', parHole8='3', parHole9='3', parHole10='', parHole11='', parHole12='', parHole13='', parHole14='', parHole15='', parHole16='', parHole17='', parHole18=''}]}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="container" th:each="course : ${courses}">
        <div class="border">
            <div id="courseDetails" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p><strong>Course Name:</strong>
                        <a th:text="${course.name}"></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div >
            <table th:each="par, index : ${course.parLists}" id="courseInfo" class="table table-bordered w-auto">
                <tr >
                    <th th:text="${'Hole'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#2'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#3'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#4'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#5'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#6'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#7'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#8'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#9'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#10'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#11'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#12'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#13'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#14'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#15'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#16'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#17'}"></th>
                    <th th:text="${'#18'}"></th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td th:text="${'Par'}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole1}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole2}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole3}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole4}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole5}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole6}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole7}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole8}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole9}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole10}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole11}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole12}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole13}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole14}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole15}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole16}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole17}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${par.parHole18}"></td>
                    <td>
```

[image]

New Course

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/discgolf/saveCourse}" th:object="${newCourse}"
                      method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
                           placeholder="Course name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
                    </div>
                    <th:block  th:object="${hole}">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="parRow" class="row g-0">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label>#1</label>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{par}" placeholder="#1">
                            </div>
                            #2 - #17
                            <div class="col">
                                <label>#18</label>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{par}" placeholder="#18">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </th:block>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save Course</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Is your example data for a 9-hole course? If so, then (a) it would probably help to have a Java field which captures that - e.g. `int holes`; (b) with `holes` you can then use that value with Thymeleaf's `${#numbers.sequence(1, holes)}`, to generate the 9 columns you need.

Comment: Even better, create a `Hole` class and only create that many instances (each with its par value) per course. Then you have a collection of holes you can iterate over, the same as you iterate over your courses.

Comment: Honestly I did consider that, but how do I add a dynamic number of holes? As I said some are 9, some are 12 some are 15, 18 etc. I added how I add a new course.

Comment: I don't know where you get your `par` data, so this is a bit speculative, but... If the `par` data for holes 10 onwards is blank/null, then you know you don't need any `Hole` objects for those. Your `List<Hole>` collection will only contain 9 `Hole` objects. Or 9 `List<Integer>` values if you just want to capture the `par` numbers.

Comment: Sorry if we're getting bogged down in details here. Perhaps this is more relevant: The principle I try to follow is: I try to make my Thymeleaf logic as simple as possible, by building a Java structure which is as easy as possible for Thymeleaf to iterate over.

Comment: Yep everything you said makes sense now, rookie error but it was a good learning curve. So I created an int array of numbers 1-18, so when I create a course I have 18 different fields but when it saves now its a list of 'Hole' objects that has in id, a number and a par. ``` [Course{id=1, name='Test Update Edit', holes=[Hole{holeId=1, number=1, par=3}, ... Hole{holeId=9, number=9, par=4}]}]``` Each hole object is linked to a course_id as well  so a course can have n holes. Thanks guy!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your `parHole` would be a `List<Int>` or `Map<Int,Int>` then you could iterate over it or its entries with `th:each` like with any list. But as you have static field names for each parHole you can't do it and you have to be repetetive like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Following Tarmo's answer, if I were you, I would convert your parList to a List of holes, add the "Hole" and "Par" as the first values in your list so they can be included as the header rows in your table, and then iterate over them. Also then you could then use index in your :each iterator to keep track of your hole numbers